# When did Derek Morgan step down and let Hotchner take over again?

Tags: criminal-minds

In season 5 of *Criminal Minds*, Hotchner comes under some scrutiny from the Bureau so he persuades Morgan to sort of switch roles with him; Morgan would lead the team at least temporarily. I remember Morgan acted like he was in charge for maybe one episode but then soon, Hotchner is back in his usual role.

**When did Hotchner take back over the team?**

Comment: He realized that Hotchner was really better qualified and cut out for the job. While Morgan was completely capable, there were responsibilities and aspects that he just didn't want. EDIT: I just realized the question said "when" and not "why". Durp...

Answer (score 1):

Episode 10 of Season 5 (The Slave of Duty) is when Hotch is temporarily absent

> While Agent Hotchner takes a leave of absence to contemplate his future with the BAU, the team is called to investigate a home invasion case in Nashville without him

He's back by Episode 12 (The Uncanny Valley).

**Out of Universe**

The absence was part of Thomas Gibson's suspension when  he allegedly pushed assistant director Ian Woolf and had to attend anger management classes but remained on the show.

Comment: When Hotchner takes over again, is there any acknowledgement in the dialogue? Something like "hey, I'm glad you're back, you're in charge again, ok?" or something?

Comment: I don't recall but Morgan only took over on the condition that he gave the role up when Hotch returned.